# Make QToolBar transparent

Tags: qt, qtoolbar

Is it possible to make a `QToolBar` widget background transparent?

Behind it I have a `QOpenGLWidget` and I'd like to only see the toolbar's icons.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with a QGroupBox in front of a QOpenGLWidget:

```
this->viewButtonBox = new QGroupBox(tr("View"));
QPalette pal;
pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::transparent);
viewButtonBox->setPalette(pal);

//adding groupbox in front of openglwidget
QVBoxLayout* centralLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
centralLayout->addWidget(viewButtonBox);
this->setLayout(centralLayout);
```

The QGroupBox is part of the QOpenGLWidgets layout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry I didn't understand what you meant with "The QGroupBox is part of the QOpenGLWidgets layout."

Comment: I added to the code to make it more clear how I set up the layout.

Comment: So you're suggesting I ditch the ToolBar and start using a GroupBox?

Comment: No, I am showing you how I set up a transparent QGroupBox in front of a QOpenGLWidget. You're problem is fairly similar, since both QGroupBox and QToolBar inherit their functionality from QWidget. This is supposed to give you a good starting point to implement your transparent QToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to declare `QToolBar` as child of `QOpenGLWidget`?
Something like:

```
QMainWindow qW;

QOpenGLWidget *pOG = new QOpenGLWidget;
QToolBar *pTB = new QToolBar(pOG);

qW.setCentralWidget(pOG);
```

I tested with a `QFrame` instead of `QOpenGLWidget` and it works.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. The toolbar is not transparent and I can't move the toolbars

Comment: You could try `pTb->setStyleSheet("background: transparent;");`